# Win 8 RT routing parameters

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have to route through different pages and pass routing parameters between them. I have made that happen and I am passing the parameters but I do not have access to the object property.

```
void itemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Views.SongPicker) , e.ClickedItem );
        }
```

and on the other page I recive the parameter object as a navigation parameter.

```
 protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

        }
```

I have no access to the object's properties. 
I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast the object to your type, like:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        var param = navigationParameter as MyType;
    }
```

And if the type is not nullable:

```
var param = (MyType)navigationParameter;
```