# Show different content on page depending on navigation parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to make a cookbook, I have a class with the recipes and with binding I'm presenting them in a page. When I click on a recipe, I want to navigate to the "recipe page" and the text, lists etc to be different depending the link that I'm coming from.

I have done the recipePage and it works only if I click the first recipe of spaggeti with the same data that I have putted on my own, is it possible to have one page and present different data as I said above?

This is the XAML binding part that I'm presenting the recipes with spaggeti

```
<Grid Margin="20,20,0,0">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Categories}" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:SpaggetiRecipe">
                <Grid   Margin="30,30,30,30" MaxWidth="230"  MaxHeight="230" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Width="160" Height="160" Source="{x:Bind SpaggetiPhoto}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind RecipeName}" Style="{StaticResource Texts}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="DarkBlue" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

and this is the C# part

```
private List<SpaggetiRecipe> Categories;

    public SpaggetiPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Categories = SpaggetiRecipeManager.GetSpaggetiRecipe();
    }

    private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var spaggetiRecipe = (SpaggetiRecipe)e.ClickedItem;
        if (spaggetiRecipe.RecipeId == 1)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Recipe));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win 8 RT routing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375845/win-8-rt-routing-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the "Drill In Page" scenario in the official [Navigation menu (XAML) sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation) to implement your own.

The key point here is using `Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object) method` or `Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object, NavigationTransitionInfo) method` instead of `Frame.Navigate(TypeName) method`. You can send `SpaggetiRecipe` or a property of `SpaggetiRecipe` like `spaggetiRecipe.RecipeId` as navigation parameter. For example:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Recipe), spaggetiRecipe);
```

Or

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Recipe), spaggetiRecipe.RecipeId);
```

Using basic type like `spaggetiRecipe.RecipeId` here is better as it supports parameter serialization using `GetNavigationState` and avoids excess memory usage caused by the frame’s navigation stack holding a reference to the parameter. For more information, see **Remarks** section in [Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh702394.aspx).

Then in the target page's `OnNavigatedTo` method, you can use `e.Parameter` to get the navigation parameter and use it to get the data that need to be used in this page.

In the official sample, the navigation parameter is a string, and itself is used as the data. In your `Recipe` page, you can use `e.Parameter` to get the `spaggetiRecipe.RecipeId` and use `RecipeId` to get the data that you want to use in your text, lists and so on. For example, you can define a `Recipe` class to store the data and a `GetRecipe` method which uses `RecipeId` as parameter to initialize it. In XAML, you can bind to it like what you have done in "recipePage".

The `Recipe` class may like:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public List<T> RecipeList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The `GetRecipe` method may like:

```
public Recipe GetRecipe(int id)
{
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    //set the data based on the id, here I use switch for example, you may get data for database or some other please
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            recipe =...;
            break;

        case 2:
             recipe =...;
            break;

        ...
    }
    return recipe;
}
```

After this, you can use `GetRecipe` to get different data.

```
public Recipe RecipeData { get; set; }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter is int)
    {
        RecipeData = GetRecipe((int)e.Parameter);
    }
    else
    {
        //Something Wrong
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Then in XAML, use bind to present data like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind RecipeData.RecipeName}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind RecipeData.RecipeList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--DataTemplate to show RecipeData.RecipeList-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```